# want to see who deleted the message on_message_delete

Tags: python, discord.py

when somenone delets a message, it returns the author name, not who deleted the message. what should i change ?

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if "discord.gg" not in message.content and "https://discord.gg/" not in message.content and "discord.gg/" not in message.content:
        log_channel = client.get_channel(N/A)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Message Deleted",
            description=f"Message sent by {message.author.name} has been deleted:\n{message.content}",
            color=discord.Color.red()
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="N/A", icon_url="N/A")
        deletor = None
        if message.guild:
            deletor = message.guild.get_member(message.author.id)
        else:
            deletor = client.get_user(message.author.id)
        if deletor:
            embed.add_field(name="Deleted By", value=deletor.name, inline=False)
        await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

i tried to use author.deleted and deleted.user.id even this

tried even to use {message.author}

````
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if "discord.gg" not in message.content and "https://discord.gg/" not in message.content and "discord.gg/" not in message.content:
        log_channel = client.get_channel(N/A)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Message Deleted",
            description=f"Message sent by **{message.author.name}** has been deleted by: **{message.author}**\n\nDeleted message:\n```{message.content}```",
            color=discord.Color.red()
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="N/A", icon_url="N/A")
        #embed.add_field(name=f"Deleted By {message.author}", inline=False)
        await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do what you want with the `on_message_delete` event. [The docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message_delete) only have it having the `discord.Message` object as a parameter and even the [discord gateway events](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#message-delete) doc only show that the event has the message ID, channel ID, and the guild ID.

The only way I can think of doing it is using the Audit Logs. Perhaps iterating through delete/bulk delete entries and finding the message that was deleted in there and trying to get the author information out of it. However, this will only work if someone else deleted someone's message - there won't be an audit log entry if an individual deleted their own message. But if you go the audit log iterating route and can't find an entry in the last minute or so then you can assume the individual was the one who deleted it.

Iterating over the audit log data gives you a series of:

- [`AuditLogAction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#auditlogentry). This has a `user` property which is the user that did the action (ie, deleted the message in your case)
- The above action has also a `action` property which will tell you what kind of action it was - ie, in your case, a `message_delete` action.
- The action object also has a `target` parameter which *should* be the message that was deleted - you might be able to retrieve the message ID from that to check if it's the same as the one that got deleted in `on_message_delete`.

Hopefully that gives you something to go off if you really want to get the user that deleted a message in `on_message_delete`.

**EDIT**: Some example code to get you started:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message: discord.Message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    guild = message.guild
    # check logs to see who deleted it
    after = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

    target = None
    async for entry in guild.audit_logs(after=after, oldest_first=False, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        # there's no way to know for certain if the entry is referring to the same message as us
        # it could go either way
        if entry.extra.channel.id != message.channel.id:
            # definitely not our message - skip
            continue
        if entry.target.id != message.author.id:
            # definitely not our message - skip
            continue
        target = entry.user
        break

    if not target:
        # couldn't find a "matching" audit log entry - deleted by message author
        target = message.author
    print(f"Message deleted by {target.name} {target.id}")
```

A few caveats:

- `on_message_delete` only works for messages in the bot's cache - you'll have to look `on_raw_message_delete` for others
- similarly, there are methods/events for bulk deleting too
- the audit log entry doesn't have the message ID of the message deleted - so we're doing the checks we can and then *assuming* that the entry is for the message that just got deleted (it is pretty likely)

Comment: So to understanf, if the sender deleted his own message then there will not be anythin even in audit log?

Comment: That's correct; the audit log only contains an entry if someone (admin/moderator/etc) deleted another user's message.

Comment: Other thrn audit log ☹️?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to find out besides from the audit log. But the `on_message_delete` event is still triggered if a user deletes their own message. So, you can listen for that event and do: "Is this message that just got deleted in the audit log?" If **yes**, then you can find out who deleted it from the log. If **no**, then we can assume it was the author of the message that deleted it. And we can then use the `message.author` property to get them.

Comment: How or where i should edit my code to make the final changes ?

Comment: I added some example code. This works for me. Make sure you add `import datetime` somewhere as well.

Answer (score 0):

done :) thanks for helping
final code

````py
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if "discord.gg" not in message.content and "https://discord.gg/" not in message.content and "discord.gg/" not in message.content:
        log_channel = client.get_channel(N/A)
        deletor = None
        async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
            deletor = entry.user
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Message Deleted",
            description=f"Message sent by **{message.author.mention}** in {message.channel.mention} has been deleted:\n\n```{message.content}```",
            color=discord.Color.red()
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="N/A", icon_url="N/A")
        if deletor:
            embed.add_field(name="Deleted By", value=f"{deletor.mention}", inline=False)
        await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
````